# How to extract default ringtones from Android device?

Tags: ringtone

I just bought a new phone and I do not like the default ringtones/notification sounds, but I like the ones on my old phone.

When I plug my old phone into my computer and go to `This PC\KYOCERA\Internal storage\media\audio\ringtones` like I have been told to go to for the default ringtones, the only ones that show up are a couple of custom ringtones I had put on previously. I want to extract the default ringtones like AT&T Play On and notification sounds like Syrma, so that I can put them on my new phone.

I would prefer not to install drivers/programs onto my computer, but it would be okay with installing an app on my phone *if necessary*. I have the default Windows 10 programs on my computer, as well as and file commander and the rest of the default Android 5 apps on my old phone.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Chances are that someone has already extracted the ringtones from the device rom and published them somewhere in the web. Just search Google for "*your-device-name* ringtones".

Answer (score 14):

You probably need a file browser on the phone to access (need root), or `adb pull`

The built-in ringtones are located in

```
/system/media/audio/ringtones
```

... instead of your *Internal Storage*.

You can also extract them from a ROM `.zip` file downloaded from elsewhere without looking into your phone. Just navigate to the same path above and take all files out there.

Comment: Just wanna add that you would not find this path `/system/media/audio/ringtones` in your mobile OR when you open your mobile (through a USB cable) on your system. Because this is a ROM path. i.e. download a ROM for your mobile; preferably a truly stock ROM (truly stock ROM means original unmodified ROM).
This ROM would be in a form of a zip file. and when you extract this zip file; there you would found this path. `/system/media/audio/ringtones`

Comment: `adb pull /system/media/audio/  ./` did the trick, special thanks

Comment: On my Pixel6a it was at `/product/media/audio/`

Answer (score 1):

You can copy internal files, ex `/system/media/audio/ringtones`, to sd card or anywhere with total commander application.

On Samsung Phone, custom ringtones seem to have to be copied in <internal storage>/music/Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thanks guys!
But, I found New Android version stored audio files in system_ext/media/audio

Answer (score 1):

On AOSP ROMs, ringtone, notification and other default sounds are located at `/product/media/audio/`

This is valid for at least Android 12+

If you do not have a root file explorer installed, you can run the following command to pull the files:

`adb pull /product/media/audio <target directory>`

This will move the content to the current working directory:

`adb pull /product/media/audio .\`

Running the above `adb` command requires USB/Wireless Debugging enabled from Developer options as well as connecting your phone to your PC.