# Where does your Samsung phone store its default ringtones?

Tags: notifications, default-applications, ringtone, samsung-galaxy-j2

So my grandma gave me a Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime from 2017, and it doesn't have any SD card inserted. *So where does my phone store its defalt ringtones and notification sounds?* I tried going to **Android>data>system>media>audio>ringtones** but it seems it doesn't have the *system* folder. Can someboy help me with this?[image]

Comment: what you are looking for is on system partition. what you see is actually just the content of emulated sdcard on userdata partition. enable usb-debugging and type *'adb shell ls /system/media/audio/ringtones'* in terminal
https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Comment: @alecxs I came to post the same path. Post your comment as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio solid answer should include how to access/copy ringtones, where to add custom ringtones and which format (ogg, mp3) on unrooted device. we have lot information already but do you know canonical location?
[How to extract default ringtones from Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/183455) //
[List of special Android SD card folders?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1658) //
[Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926) //
[What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205430)

Comment: @alecxs "do you know canonical location?" No, I don't. However, I have checked a Samsung and a non-Sansung phones; Both have the sounds located on `/system/media/audio/` with these 3 sub-folders being common: `notifications`, `ringtones` and `ui`. The non-Samsung phone also add a sub-folder `alarms`. All of them contain files with `ogg` format only. Does/do your phone(s) have different formats?