# How to get file currently set as notification sound?

Tags: samsung, notifications, file-system, android-10, media-files

I just changed my phone - migrated everything and it works great.

One thing that grinds my gear and that I cannot manage to work out is: **how to get file currently set as notification sound** on my first Android phone to copy to another one?

What I tried:

1. I know, that files that are possible to set as notification sound are supposed to be **in a special Notifications folder, but file is simply not there**. In Settings the file is visible as currently set, but when I try to change the file for notification, it's not on the list.
2. This **file WORKS** (sound of notification works fine with this file), although **searching for it with special (SolidExplorer) or integrated file managers does not give any results** - file not found.

**My phone**: Samsung Galaxy A7 (2018), Android 10 (newest software possible for me), not rooted or anything (work phone that I cannot mess around with).

This is driving me crazy. Looks like file was "cached" somehow and works (so it must exist somewhere in memory), but it's unsearchable. After restart - notification sound still works with this file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Adam

Comment: Have you checked the path mentioned in this answer? https://android.stackexchange.com/a/183456/2241

Comment: @Robert it needs root. As I mentioned - I have no root and cannot root the device, as it is company device.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to see files with Solid Explorer - file is not visible in mentioned path:
/system/media/audio/ringtones

Comment: Most likely you don't see files even if they exist in Solid Explorer. Use `adb´, that way it does not need root.

Comment: @Robert please see update - unfortunately, file is not there.

Comment: As I wrote most likely you don't see any files in this path because SolidExplorer doesn't has permission to se them.

Comment: @Robert I do see other files there.

Comment: Use adb. Approach: run `adb shell`, then `settings list system | grep notification`. In the output look for a key/name that appears like notification_sound or notification_audio. Next to that would be a = sign followed by `content://media/SOME_ABC`. In that case, note down that complete `content://...` path. Now run, `content query --uri CONTENT_PATH`. Replace CONTENT_PATH with the one you noted down above. In the output, look for "_data" or "data" or "file" or something like that. That should tell you the exact path where the notification sound can be found. Report your findings/errors here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, unfortunately, it seems that **it is not possible to get this file the easy way** (requires additional software or rooting the phone, connecting to PC with additional programs to go through files, trying different paths to check if file even exists etc.).

I had to return the phone and never figured it out.

It was a very specific situation, when the file was not listed among other notification sound files anymore.